# Как занести выбранные элементы из json в массив PHP

Tags: php, json

Подскажите как занести из json файла в массив double все элементы link через for()?

`[{"_id":"2","link":"t.me\/vamix"},{"_id":"1","link":"t.me\/texas"}]`

```
    $double = [];
    $q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM black ORDER BY _id DESC");
    while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) $output[] = $e;
    $string = json_encode($output);
    print($string);
```

Comment: Надо выучить синтаксис for

Comment: А вообще это можно сделать просто через array_column

Comment: А если из БД надо было только link вытягивать, тогда достаточно было другой запрос прописать с самого начала

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$json = '[{"_id":"2","link":"t.me\/vamix"},{"_id":"1","link":"t.me\/texas"}]';
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$arrLength = count($arr);

// С помощью for
$double = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < $arrLength; $i++) {
    $double[] = $arr[$i]['link'];
}
print_r($double); // Array ( [0] => t.me/vamix [1] => t.me/texas )

// С помощью foreach
$double = [];
foreach ($arr as $item) {
    $double[] = $item['link'];
}
print_r($double); // Array ( [0] => t.me/vamix [1] => t.me/texas )
```